# Using the firefox plug-in Down Them All is there a way to perform the dTa one click on a range of pages?

Tags: firefox, javascript

So I have a url: `http://www.example.com/mp3?page=1`. Which has a load of free mp3s to download on each page.

---

But rather than:
clicking dTa one click,
then changing page to `http://www.example.com/mp3?page=2`,
then clicking dTa one click,
etc...

I would like to be able to select a range of pages to perform the firefox extension.

---

Could I write a JS function to put onto the page:

- Perform "dTa one click" firefox extension
- `var page_number = 1`
- `window.open ('http://www.example.com/mp3?page='+page_number+','_self',false)`
- Perform "dTa one click" firefox extension
- `var page_number = page_number + 1`
- `window.open ('http://www.example.com/mp3?page='+page_number+','_self',false)`
- etc......

---

#### Has any one got any ideas of how I should go about doing this?

Comment: You could save all the pages locally using DTA, then merge the files together to give you a 'super-page', from which you could use the DTA extension to download all the links.

Answer (score 0):

There are several Firefox plugins which allow you to inject your custom scripts in web pages from specific domains. Check out [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) and [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/). Personally, I prefer Stylish, but Greasemonkey has many more contributed user scripts. If you do a search, you might even find that the script that you need already exists...

Answer (score 0):

There are tools that can download complete websites. I don't know the name of what I've used, but I know they have options to download only specific filetypes like mp3, to not follow links outside the domain, etc. This is probably a lot easier to use. Even if this downloads the HTML pages as well, those are easily deleted afterwards. So the question is if you want to get the firefox method working just because, or if you want to get results.

http://www.httrack.com/page/2/